# Se cierra la app cuando intento enviar un pdf (Al mandar texto funciona)

Tags: android, mensajes

```
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        //sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
        //sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        sendIntent.setType("application/pdf");

        Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null);
        startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Mi objetivo es que de la opción de compartir un pdf desde la app de android. Estoy usando java.
El pdf se crea correctamente en file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/
Sin embargo, no se comparte, se crea el archivo y se cierra la app.

¿Puede ser que falte algún permiso en el manifiesto?

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Me deja mandar mensajes desde la app hacia whatsapp cuando comento lo que no funciona y descomento el codigo comentado, dando la opción de elegir el usuario receptor.

¿Alguien puede saber por qué pasa esto? ¿Alguna pista?

Gracias.

Comment: Usas algún framework o libreria de terceros? Porque ese comportamiento es típico de ellos

Comment: y el mensaje del LogCat? si realizas aplicaciones android, el uso del LogCat es esencial.

Answer (score 0):

para compartir un archivo se an agregado algunas restricciones, ahora debes utilizar FileProvider para poder compartir estos archivos.

En el momento de crear tu uri supongo que utilizas un Uri from file
deberas tener algo parecido a esto:

```
File dir = new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/PDF"));
file = new File(dir, nombreArchivo);

    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(PdfView.this, PdfView.this.getPackageName() + ".provider",file,nombreArchivo);

final Intent compartir = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, destinatarios)
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Envio de archivos PDF")
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Se adjunta Nomina Cuprosa")
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
                    .setType("application/pdf");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartir,"Compartir PDF"));
```